# How to find indices for sequential NaNs at the start and end of a1D NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D NumPy array that contains both floating point numbers and NaNs. There will almost always be multiple sequential NaNs at the start and end of the array with some NaNs throughout the middle of the array. There is no way to predict in advance the location or number of NaNs present in the array.

What I am trying to do:

- Retrieve indices of sequential NaNs occurring at the **Start** of the array and the **End** of the array only
- Not retrieve indices for NaNs in the middle of the array
- Avoid the use of loops/list comprehensions (if possible)

Below is a short example illustrating the type of array I am working with (actual arrays will have 1e3 to 1e9 elements).

```
data = np.array([NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.2, 3.4, 5.0, NaN, 3.3, 3.2, NaN, NaN, 4.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN])
```

For this array I would like to retrieve the following indices:

```
idx = [0, 1, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: What constitutes being in the middle? Is it a specified range or just a single middle value?

Comment: The "middle" would be anything from the first non-Nan element to the last non-Nan element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a mask of all the NaNs, using [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
mask = np.isnan(data)
```

Now notice that [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) always return the *first* instance of the minimum value:

```
leading_nans = mask.argmin()
```

You can reverse an array without copying any data using a simple slice:

```
trailing_nans = mask[::-1].argmin()
```

Either of these can be zero. Either way, you can now concatenate two ranges to get the actual indices:

```
nan_indices = np.concatenate((np.arange(leading_nans), np.arange(data.size - trailing_nans, data.size))
```

If you want a mask instead:

```
nan_mask = np.zeros(data.size, dtype=bool)
nan_mask[:leading_nans] = True
nan_mask[-trailing_nans:] = True
```

Comment: @WesH. Glad it does. It was totally untested :)